# Replace string in dataframe with different column values

Tags: r, string, replace

I have dataframe that looks like:

```
 Tester Type    Subject Type    Time        1     2     3
 TType1         SType1          Day 1       11    2     1         
 TType1         SType2          Day 1       3     2     13
 TType1         SType1          Day 2       2     3     15
 TType2         SType3          Day 2       1     4     3
 TType3         SType3          Day 2       2     3     4
 TType1         SType1          Day 1       7     2     2
 TType2         SType1          Day 2       2     6     7
```

I'm trying to find all SType 1 in Subject Type column and replace it with Values in Tester Type. So, my output would look like:

```
 Tester Type    Subject Type    Time        1     2     3
 TType1         TType1          Day 1       11    2     1         
 TType1         SType2          Day 1       3     2     13
 TType1         TType1          Day 2       2     3     15
 TType2         SType3          Day 2       1     4     3
 TType3         SType3          Day 2       2     3     4
 TType1         TType1          Day 1       7     2     2
 TType2         TType2          Day 2       2     6     7
```

Comment: What did you try so far? There is a lot of resources on this site to perform such operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace value in column with corresponding value from another column in same dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814515/replace-value-in-column-with-corresponding-value-from-another-column-in-same-dat)

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814515/replace-value-in-column-with-corresponding-value-from-another-column-in-same-dat?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(df$SubjectType == "SType1", df$TesterType, df$SubjectType)
# [1] "TType1" "SType2" "TType1" "SType3" "SType3" "TType1" "TType2"
```

Assuming `df` as your data frame.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), using the logical condition as 'i', we assign (`:=`) the 'SubjectType' that corresponds to the rows in 'i' as 'TesterType'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[SubjectType=='SType1', SubjectType := TesterType]
df1
#   TesterType SubjectType  Time X1 X2 X3
#1:     TType1      TType1 Day 1 11  2  1
#2:     TType1      SType2 Day 1  3  2 13
#3:     TType1      TType1 Day 2  2  3 15
#4:     TType2      SType3 Day 2  1  4  3
#5:     TType3      SType3 Day 2  2  3  4
#6:     TType1      TType1 Day 1  7  2  2
#7:     TType2      TType2 Day 2  2  6  7
```