# R - split alphanumeric char observations with column for each letter factor with value of numeric for each observation

Tags: r, regex, string

I am not quite sure how to best word the title for what I want to do.

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
 observation = c("a2", NA, "b3", "c5", NA, "b", "a3")
 df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, observation))

 df

  ID observation
1  1          a2
2  2        <NA>
3  3          b3
4  4          c5
5  5        <NA>
6  6           b
7  7          a3
```

My desired output is a data frame that splits observations by numbers and letters, with a new column for each unique letter where each row contains the associated observation number for that letter.

The desired output should look like this:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, a = c(2, NA, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 3), 
                                   b = c(0, NA, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                   c = c(0, NA, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0)))
desired_df

  ID  a  b  c
1  1  2  0  0
2  2 NA NA NA
3  3  0  3  0
4  4  0  0  5
5  5  0 NA NA
6  6  0  0  0
7  7  3  0  0
```

I've tried approaching this by splitting observations into letters and numbers with a regular expression and saving the result into a new column:

```
library(stringr)
char <- unlist(str_replace_all(observation, "[[:digit:]]", ""))
num <- unlist(str_extract(observation, "[[:digit:]]"))
df_new <- cbind(ID, char, num)
df_new

  ID char  num
1  1    a    2
2  2 <NA> <NA>
3  3    b    3
4  4    c    5
5  5 <NA> <NA>
6  6    b <NA>
7  7    a    3
```

Then tried converting char to a factors to a binary form based on the answer to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990760/converting-factors-to-binary-in-r)

```
df_new <- data.frame(cbind(df, sapply(levels(as.factor((char))), 
function(x) as.integer(x == char))))

  ID char  num  a  b  c
1  1    a    2  1  0  0
2  2 <NA> <NA> NA NA NA
3  3    b    3  0  1  0
4  4    c    5  0  0  1
5  5 <NA> <NA> NA NA NA
6  6    b <NA>  0  1  0
7  7    a    3  1  0  0
```

I then tried to replace each 1 observation with the the corresponding value in df_new1$num for that row, based on the answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814515/replace-value-in-column-with-corresponding-value-from-another-column-in-same-dat):

```
df_new2 <- data.frame(with(df_new1, ifelse(df_new1 == 1, df_new1$num, 0)))

df_new2
  ID char num  a  b  c
1  1    0   0  1  0  0
2  0   NA  NA NA NA NA
3  0    0   0  0  2  0
4  0    0   0  0  0  3
5  0   NA  NA NA NA NA
6  0    0  NA  0 NA  0
7  0    0   0  2  0  0
```

Which outputs the wrong result. I've been struggling to figure this out. I am OK with all non 1 values being replaced with 0 as long as the values in columns a, b, c are correct.

I'm not sure if splitting letters and numbers into separate columns, and trying to replace binary observations for letters as factors is even the best approach for trying to solve my original problem and am open to any approach that works.

My real data frame is generated by a script that extracts patterns from .txt files, where the alphanumeric observations vary from file to file. I need something that will work for any unique letters that get assigned to the char column.

I appreciate any advice or help on figuring this out as I am a novice to R. I'm still getting familiar with SO etiquette and would appreciate any comments on how to improve the question and/or reproducible example.

Comment: You can use the `spread` function from the `tidyr` package.  `df_new <- data.frame(ID, char, num, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` then `spread(df_new, char, num)`  this will then take some work to clean up all of the NAs

Comment: Your desire output has an `ID == 7` row. Is this a typo?

Comment: @UseR, yes, thanks for catching that. I fixed it in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract` from `tidyr` to split `observation` into `var` and `value` column, then use `spread` to reshape the table. Note that `<NA>` is now its own column because of the NA values in `ID == 2`. A `select` gets rid of that column:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  extract(observation, c("var", "value"), regex = "([a-z])?(\\d)?") %>%
  spread(var, value) %>%
  select(-`<NA>`)
```

**Result:**

```
  ID    a    b    c
1  1    2 <NA> <NA>
2  2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  3 <NA>    3 <NA>
4  4 <NA> <NA>    5
5  5 <NA> <NA> <NA>
6  6    3 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works very well with the example data frame, however when I try to apply it to my real data frame I get an error  "Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a list". @UseR Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot?

Comment: @Phono Without looking at your real data, it's pretty difficult to tell what's the issue. Could you provide a sample dataset that maybe better represent your real data?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that non-digit values can be `0` or `NA`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  nest(-ID) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~data.frame(key = gsub("\\d", "", unlist(.x)), val = gsub("\\D", "", unlist(.x))))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  spread(key, val, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-ncol(.)) %>%
  replace(.=="", 0)

  # ID    a     b     c    
  # <fct> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 1     2     0     0    
# 2 2     0     0     0    
# 3 3     0     3     0    
# 4 4     0     0     5    
# 5 5     0     0     0    
# 6 6     3     0     0    
# There were 14 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Comment: This worked well for both the example df and my actual df. Thanks!